# Can Spark-Cassandra-Connector know if whole Cassandra table is selected for DirectJoin with Dataframe?

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I am using DirectJoin of Spark-Cassandra-Connector (SCC) in order to join a dataframe with a cassandra table and then perform a count. When I Join on all the data from the table the Join is faster (5 minutes), than when I Join on e.g. 3/4 of it (13 minutes). Can SCC somehow know if I have chosen all the partition keys in order to perform a join?

My guess is that due to the fact that I am not using RepartitionByCassandraReplica sometimes some partition keys are sent to the right nodes and some other times not. So maybe the 5 minutes is just "luck"?

**Edit**

DirectJoin is always "on" on both the above cases!

Answer (score 3):

Direct join issues a query for each join key. That's why full join of two tables is faster without direct join.
By default direct join is disabled if the size ratio exceeds 90% (directJoinSetting=auto, directJoinSizeRatio=0.9).

You can also force direct join by setting directJoinSetting=on, disable with directJoinSetting=off, or tune the threshold with directJoinSizeRatio=x. See https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/reference.md#cassandra-datasource-table-options for details.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I am not sure I understand the "That's why full join of two tables is faster without direct join". It is faster because DirectJoin is deactivated?
I should have made clear that the above is always with DIrectJoin "on", in both cases.

Comment: >  It is faster because DirectJoin is deactivated?
yes

Comment: Just to be on the safe side, you can confirm that direct join is used for both of your joins by inspecting the `explain()` output.

Comment: Also, your guess seams reasonable to me. The processing time may differ for different data distributions.

Comment: So I tried with explain in both cases and I got a Cassandra Direct Join both times. So it seems that it could be because of different data distribution every time. The point is that I tried many many times with both scenarios and I always get 17 mins with 3/4 of data and 5 mins with all the data which is a bit weird. I would expect at least sometimes the times to be different...

Comment: ok, I think I figured it out. If the partition keys of the dataframe are sorted in ASC then it takes 5 minutes. If they do not have a sorting then it takes also 17 minutes. It seems sorting plays indeed an important role!